# Format double with leading space in xaml for a label

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I cannot manage to format double values with leading spaces for labels in XAML.

The leading spaces are necessary for me, because I want labels to display a certain number of characters for the purpose of alignment:

```
<Viewbox Grid.Column="1" >
   <Label xml:space="preserve" Content="{Binding PwVal, FallbackValue='Power'}" ContentStringFormat='#####.0' Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0" FontFamily="Consolas">
   </Label>
</Viewbox>
```

The `ContentStringFormat='#####.0'` does not work. However, `'0000.0'` gives leading zeros, but what I want is leading spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting):

```
<Label ... ContentStringFormat="{}{0,7:0.0} />
```

Instead of a Label, better use the simpler TextBlock element instead of a Label, and bind its Text property with an appropriate StringFormat:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding PwVal, StringFormat={}{0,7:0.0}}" ... />
```

Comment: this works: "7:0.0", and TextBlock is really what should be used - here only text displaying is needed. I read "Difference between Label and TextBlock". Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would be inclined to use a TextBlock.

However. Maybe you really need a Label for whatever reason.

When you bind Content of a Label to something then the usual behaviour is that the control puts a textblock in it's contents. It is this which presents the bound data.

A Label is a type of contentcontrol.

An oddity of this behaviour is that it then uses it's ContentStringFormat to format the data goes into that textblock.

Hence you can alternatively do something like:

```
    <Label Content="{Binding PwVal}"
           ContentStringFormat="{}{0,6:0.0}"
           />
```

Note the ContentStringFormat.

I added some markup to prove to myself that I was getting two spaces before my bound value.

```
    <Label Content="{Binding PwVal}"
           BorderBrush="Black"
           BorderThickness="2"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           ContentStringFormat="{}{0,6:0.0}"
           />
```